# Comparing char to string index in java vs python

Tags: java, python, string, char, dna-sequence

I realize there are many answers that simply solve how to do it in Java, but am looking for a solution that is **conceptually similar to an implementation I might perform in a Python program**, since that is far more familiar to me.

My Java function `cgRatio` takes a DNA string and goes through every index to count the occurrence of "C" and "G" character values in the string and return the ratio relative to the length of the string.  For example, if I pass the following string as the argument for the function:
`"ATGGCGCATTAA"` I would get a return value of 5/12 or a float of `4.1666...`

In Python, this function could be written as so:

```
def cgRatio(dna):
count = 0
for i in range(len(dna)):
    if dna[i] == "C" or dna[i] == "G":
        count += 1
return 1.0 * count/len(dna)
```

A simple `print cgRatio("ATGGCGCATTAA")` will produce the desired result.

I've seen solutions such as taking `dna.charAt(i)` and converting that back to a string or instantiating new `char` objects at the start of the function for comparisons.  This seems overly complicated for such a simple task.  Is Python just superior in this task or is there a more efficient way to go about this in Java?

Comment: Why would you convert it back to a string?

Comment: I want to compare the string at an index to a character.  Python doesn't care but Java will not let me just dna[index] == "C".  The Java implementation of it would look something like dna.charAt(index) == ___ but I can't use "C" because it reads it as a string.

Comment: No, Java needs `dna[index].equals("C")`.

Comment: @ASwiftPeregrine Compare `dna.charAt(index)` with `'C'` instead of `"C"`? Why would you use a string literal instead of a character literal?

Comment: @StefanPochmann this was what I wasn't understanding.  I noticed that in GhostCat code and noticed in Python vs Java that single vs double quotes have different purposes.  Java likes to separate the objects as characters and strings so single and double quotes have unique meanings.  Python doesn't care unless you are just matching them (in my limited experience with both).

Comment: Btw, a much better way would be `def cgRatio(dna): return float(dna.count('C') + dna.count('G')) / len(dna)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple java code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dna.length(); i++) {
  char c = dna.charAt(i);        
  if (c == 'C' || c == 'G') { 
    count++;
  }
}
return (double)count / dna.length();
```

There is absolutely no reason to convert chars to "string" in order to compare them!

And in case you are looking for even "less" code solutions, you could be using "for each" style:

```
for (char c : dna.toCharArray()) {
```

Easy to understand, nice to read, but comes at the cost of creating a [new char array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

Comment: Or shorter to get the same number of lines as in Phyton: `if (dna.charAt(i) == 'C' || dna.charAt(i) == 'G')`. So Python is not superior to Java.

Comment: @Sayse I know, but I don't like superior.

Comment: Another caveat: `dna.length()` is invoked as many times as the string is long + 1. Python also does not do this. If your string is gigabytes long, extract it to a variable.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus If the string is gigabytes long, then the problem starts by using a string in the first place. I am pretty sure that a python-based solution using such huge strings would be doing much worse regarding raw performance; even with the repeated calls to `length()`. The question is if he aims for **performance** or **good to read** here.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus - Not necessarily.  Since `String` is a built-in type, the JIT compiler might know that a `String` is immutable and the `length()` call can be hoisted.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.  It's amazing how much I can learn from a light discussion like this.